# Can you explain this probability question?

Tags: probability

Since $X$ and $Y$ are based on the same distribution, then by symmetry 
 $$P(X > Y ) = P(Y > X),$$ 
and 
$$P(X > Y ) + P(Y > X) + P(X = Y ) = 1.$$

Thus:
$$P(X > Y) = \frac{(1-P)(X=Y)}{2} =\frac{1 - \frac{p^2}{1-q^2}}{2}.$$
I understand all of the solution except why it's being divided by 2. Can you please explain?

Comment: $\frac{(1-P)(X=Y)}{2}$ this I don't understand. Pls explain.

Answer (score 6):

$$P(X>Y) = \frac{2P(X>Y)}{2}= \frac{P(X>Y) + P(Y>X)}{2} = \frac{1 - P(X=Y)}{2}.$$

Comment: It is explained now.

Comment: @J.banks When a question you ask gets a satisfactory answer you should accept it (the check mark). You can also upvote it (the up arrow). In fact you can upvote more than one answer (but can accept only one).